# Redirect particular post on custom url

Tags: wordpress, redirect, post, init

I want to redirect any post that have particular meta, I have tried the following code:

```
function my_call_back() {
    if( is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', true );
        if( $meta == 'my_value' ) {
            wp_redirect( 'http://google.com' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_call_back' );
```

But the `$post` variable returns empty value, so I can't use `global $post` in the `init` hook.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you hook into `init` which is a bit too early. Try hooking your function to `template_redirect` instead, like so:

```
function my_call_back() {
    if( is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', true );
        if( $meta == 'my_value' ) {
            wp_redirect( 'http://google.com' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_call_back' );
```